# Method to solve for a number in modulus equation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

If you had an equation of 12 = (8000 + B) mod 13

You could guess and check a little and arrive at B = 7.

My question is what is the best way to solve these? Is there a defined method to get B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce  $8000 \equiv 5\pmod{13}$ and get $12 \equiv (5 + B) \pmod{13}$ then subtract $5$ from each side.

Added: You can use long division to find the remainder of $8000$ divided by $13$ is $5$.  In other words, $8000 = 615 * 13 + 5$, so $8000 \equiv 5 \pmod{13}$

Comment: Can you explain the reduction to 8000≡5(mod13)  ? That's the only part I'm not following.

Comment: So will this method work for all forms of this type?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly.  If you divide $a$ by $b$ and get a remainder of $R$, then it is always true that $a \equiv R \pmod{b}$